# How to convert an UUID into a MongoDB oid

Tags: mongodb, scala, uuid, reactivemongo

Given an `java.util.UUID` generated like this...

```
import java.util.UUID

val uuid = UUID.randomUUID
```

... is it possible to convert it into a MongoDB `ObjectID` and preserve uniqueness? Or shall I just set `_id` to the UUID value?

Of course, the best solution would be to use `BSONObjectID.generate`... but in my case I get a **JSON Web Token** with an UUID as its ID, and I need to trace it in a MongoDB collection.

Tx.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Do you just want to store your UUID and don't know what type to use for the attribute? Or do you want to use the value of your UUID for your _id attribute?

Comment: I want to use the value of the UUID for the _id attribute... and store it as a standard 12-byte BSON value.

Comment: "and preserve uniqueness" - UUID is a 128-bit value. ObjectId is 96-bit. So no, not without losing _some_ uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply save `_id = uuid` ?

MongoDB will handle it simply :)

Comment: Tried... but it doesn't work. ReactiveMongo just crashes because the object id is invalid.

Comment: It's seem thant ReactiveMongo NEED an ObjectId for _id field. You can just lets him handle, and use your own field, and make an ensureIndex({ownfield:1}, {unique:true})

Comment: @twillouer Could you elaborate a bit more?
How to implement in models?

Answer (score 1):

The following implicit objects allow reactivemongo to convert UUID into BSONBinary.

```
  implicit val uuidBSONWriter: BSONWriter[UUID, BSONBinary] =
    new BSONWriter[UUID, BSONBinary] {
      override def write(uuid: UUID): BSONBinary = {
        val ba: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16)
        val da: DataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(ba)
        da.writeLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits)
        da.writeLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits)
        BSONBinary(ba.toByteArray, Subtype.OldUuidSubtype)
      }
    }

  implicit val uuidBSONReader: BSONReader[BSONBinary, UUID] =
    new BSONReader[BSONBinary, UUID] {
      override def read(bson: BSONBinary): UUID = {
        val ba = bson.byteArray
        new UUID(getLong(ba, 0), getLong(ba, 8))
      }
    }

  def getLong(array:Array[Byte], offset:Int):Long = {
    (array(offset).toLong & 0xff) << 56 |
    (array(offset+1).toLong & 0xff) << 48 |
    (array(offset+2).toLong & 0xff) << 40 |
    (array(offset+3).toLong & 0xff) << 32 |
    (array(offset+4).toLong & 0xff) << 24 |
    (array(offset+5).toLong & 0xff) << 16 |
    (array(offset+6).toLong & 0xff) << 8 |
    (array(offset+7).toLong & 0xff)
  }
```

The following is an example to use the above writer and reader objects

```
abstract class EntityDao[E <: Entity](db: => DB, collectionName: String) {

  val ATTR_ENTITY_UUID = "entityUuid"

  val collection = db[BSONCollection](collectionName)

  def ensureIndices(): Future[Boolean] = {
    collection.indexesManager.ensure(
      Index(Seq(ATTR_ENTITY_UUID -> IndexType.Ascending),unique = true)
    )
  }

  def createEntity(entity: E) = {
    val entityBSON = BSONDocument(ATTR_ENTITY_UUID -> entity.entityUuid)
    collection.insert(entityBSON)
  }

  def findByUuid(uuid: UUID)(implicit reader: BSONDocumentReader[E]): Future[Option[E]] = {
    val selector = BSONDocument(ATTR_ENTITY_UUID -> uuid)
    collection.find(selector).one[E]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative BSON handler implementation for UUID without manual bit twiddling:

```
import reactivemongo.bson._
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.UUID

implicit val uuidBSONHandler: BSONHandler[BSONBinary, UUID] = BSONHandler(
  { bson =>
    val lb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bson.byteArray).asLongBuffer
    new UUID(lb.get(0), lb.get(1))
  },
  { uuid =>
    val arr = Array.ofDim[Byte](16)
    ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).asLongBuffer.put(uuid.getMostSignificantBits).put(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits)
    BSONBinary(arr, Subtype.UuidSubtype)
  })
```